# AngularJS at server-side with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Is AngularJS only a frontend framework or it can also be used in server-side programming using node.js?

If it is possible to use AngularJS on server-side then what would be best strategy of AngularJS work on both server and client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a node module, you can find it here: [Angular.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular)

Comment: It should be noted that Angular's existence on NPM (currently) is more for distribution / package management needs, than as a module that is intended for server-side Node.js Angular development, a little more info here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2877